# Does Stack Overflow handle reputation overflow? Have the rules changed during time?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Stack Overflow has existed since 2008. Until now it's been about 4 years, so about 1460 days. With maximum 200 reputation per day, that means since the beginning of SO, the maximum reputation is about 292k for a "genius as god" user.

- How is it possible to have a user with more than 300K reputation?
- Does this mean that Stack Overflow rules have changed during its history?
- Did the one time "accept" per question with 5 more reputation than normal votes lead to all the differences?

Comment: I know the FAq with +10 on upvote +15 accepted -2 downvote etc ... but the question is iriented on "how it's possible to make so much differences ?" In fact Did historicaly stackoverflow rules have changed .. (like the vote limit, rputation limit etc ...)

Comment: from faq "A maximum of +200 reputation may be gained per day. Accepted answers are immune to this cap (source) as are bounties (source). "... My english understanding is poor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation daily limit of 200 points applies only to upvotes. So one can gain more points by having their answers being accepted even after they had reached 200 points in a given day. Also, by gaining points from answering bounty questions.

Quoting SO faq:

`Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.`

Have a look at [Jon Skeet's reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation), you can see he gains more points from users accepting his posts as answers.

Comment: @Emmanuel Devaux: It does. Someone writes 20 answers per day, he can gain 200 rep max per day from these 20 answers. But if all 20 are accepted he suddenly has additional 300 reputation (a total of 500 per day). Reputation from accepting answers is not honoring the daily rep cap.

Comment: That's a pertinent remarks ... in fact not limited to 200 but 500 for a "genious as god" user. after computation it's about 730k reputations if present rules has never changed ... So Jon Skeet is not "Genious as god" he's just "Genious as no one" :)

Comment: @Em: The limit is only for upvotes. There's **no** limit for accepts and bounties. Some users even achieved >1K per day by bounties. If you expand the rep graph details (click a random stack bar), you'll see that 10 points for each upvote stops at a certain point (after having 20 of them), but the accepts keep counting up.

Comment: Additionally, the limit doesn't apply to the 2 points added for accepting an answer on your question...